# Ubuntu 14.04, black screen after applying nVidia 352.63

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to ubunutu and are experiencing some problems with using the newest nVidia driver 352.63 from nvidia-352 (Proprietary, Tested).

After applying it (In software & updates -> additional drivers) and rebooted my system i got a black screen when the login was supposed to appear. I did find a work-around, by closing the lid so my system will hibernate, and when it wake up i can see the login

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a i7-3630QM, and a Geforce GT 640M LE

I like to add that i also experienced problems with the nVidia driver on Windows

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason why not to use Ubuntu 16.04? It has the latest drivers. Maybe your problem was a bug already solved in a newer ubuntu.

Comment: No. I will try 16.04 and post back

Comment: Upgraded to 16.04 and i can see i'm using nvidia 362.41 driver now, without getting the black screen. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds of nvidia related bugs (current open bugs [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings)). Many have been solved in recent driver releases.

As you are using Ubuntu 14.04, I suggest you try the latest drivers. You can either change the distro to 16.04, or install the newest drivers manually. [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/nvidia-settings) you find the latest drivers for Xenial (16.04). To install, download the .tar.gz file, extract, and run from terminal as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**Note**: using newer packages might be risky, as some dependencies might be needed which could conflict with current ones.

Comment: I upgraded to 16.04 so can't try it out :( But the upgrade did the trick for me, ty anyway for you suggestion

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark the answer as Solved.